# (DRF) Unable to pass in <int:id> to function via axios post request

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to axios to send `id=1` to the django `url.py`.

frontend:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
});

await axiosInstance.post(`api/public/favourites/1/`, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  }
    });
```

url.py

```
path('public/favourites/<int:id>/', add_favourites, name='add_favourites'),
```

view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_favourites(request, id):
    thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, id=id)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        if thread.liked.filter(username=request.user.username).exists():
            thread.liked.remove(request.user.username)
        
        else:
            thread.liked.add(request.user.username)
        
        return Response(thread, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However, I kept receiving error: `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.` I really can't find anything wrong in `url.py` & `view.py`, so I suspect there are mistakes in the axios request, I have tried deleting my whole database & removing all the migrations, still no luck.

Anybody has an idea what is going on about the error? Much appreciated.

Edit:
error full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1988, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\jtravel\api\views.py", line 38, in add_favourites
    thread.liked.add(request.user.username)
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1048, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1263, in _add_items
    target_ids = self._get_target_ids(target_field_name, objs)
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1197, in _get_target_ids
    target_ids.add(target_field.get_prep_value(obj))
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1132, in get_prep_value
    return self.target_field.get_prep_value(value)
  File "c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.
```

model.py

```
def thread_image_path(instance, filename):
    path = 'images/threads/thread_username_%s' % instance.username
    format = filename
    return os.path.join(path, format)
    

class Thread(models.Model):
  
    options = (('active', 'Active'), ('deactivated', 'Deactivated'))

    username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    alt = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=thread_image_path, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name='liked')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=options, default='active')
```

serializer.py

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    profile_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_profile_image')
    username_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_username')
    liked = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Account.objects.all(), many=True, slug_field='username') 
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = (
                  'id',
                  'username',
                  'username_display',
                  'profile_image',
                  'alt', 
                  'image', 
                  'content', 
                  'liked',
                  'created', 
                  'status')
        
    def get_profile_image(self, thread):
        profile_image_url = thread.username.profile_image.url
        return profile_image_url
    
    def get_username(self, thread):
        return thread.username.username
```

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to your question?

Comment: Sure. I have included it

Comment: Not sure what type of field `Thread.liked` is but you probably want to pass the actual user object and not the username, that's where your error comes from - `thread.liked.add(request.user)` / `thread.liked.remove(request.user)`

Comment: After I changed it to get the user object, I got an new error ```TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000001C24D637190>>.```. I have included the model.py & serializer.py, if you want to check it out

Comment: Looks like you're not authenticated, you'll need the user to be logged in for your view from the looks of it. How does the Account model relate to the User model? You need to pass an Account instance from an authorised user to the `add` and `remove` methods

Comment: Account is my custom User model. But I have make sure that my ```permission_classes = (AllowAny,)```, and I have tried including the authorization header in the axios request just in case. However, received the same error

Comment: If you are still getting AnonymousUser... how is auth configured in your DRF settings? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined

Comment: I am using the JWT authentication. ```REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}```